# How to create a left outer join to one table using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm struggling to understand how to use left outer join targeting a single table in SQLAlchemy.

I have the following SQL query:

```
select r1.*, r1.result as result1, r2.result as result2 
from 
    (
        select * from participation 
        where day_id = 1 
        and sport_id = 1
    )
    r1 
left join 
    (
        select * from participation
        where day_id = 3
        and sport_id = 1
    )
    r2 
on r1.participant_id = r2.participant_id
```

Which gives me the following resultset:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| participant_id | sport_id | day_id | result | result1 | result2 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|              1 |        1 |      1 |      7 |       7 |       7 |
|              2 |        1 |      1 |     13 |      13 |         |
|              3 |        1 |      1 |      0 |       0 |       1 |
|              4 |        1 |      1 |      5 |       5 |       5 |
|              5 |        1 |      1 |     20 |      20 |      21 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I currently have the following SQLAlchemy script:

```
results = db.session.query(Participation). \
    <maybe something here?>
    all()
```

But that returns each result as its own row. Can anyone point out what I need to make that work?

Comment: This question lacks a proper [mcve]. The 2 queries are wildly different. Please provide a small set of sample data, your models, and what you'd like to receive as a result from them. Answering the "how to represent the following SQL / left outer join a single table" part is simple, but the rest is a mystery.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the original question to be as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information given you simply need to [alias a subquery](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#selecting-entities-from-subqueries) twice and [outerjoin](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.outerjoin):

```
r1 = aliased(
    Participation,
    db.session.query(Participation).
        filter_by(day_id=1, sport_id=1).
        subquery())

r2 = aliased(
    Participation,
    db.session.query(Participation).
        filter_by(day_id=3, sport_id=1).
        subquery())

results = db.session.query(r1, r2.result, ...).\
    ...
    outerjoin(r2, r1.participant_id == r2.participant_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. That doesn't seem to work, though. Now I get:

    sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) missing FROM-clause entry for table "anon_2"
LINE 4: ... = 3 AND participation.sport_id = 1) AS anon_1 ON anon_2.par...

Comment: Oops, sorry my bad. I missed that changed query part in the results. Thanks I'll mark this as accepted!